# Is there "Joker interviewing on a talk show" in DC comic books too?

Tags: comics

There are two scenes in movies that the Joker had interviewed on a TV channel.

One in the *Joker* (2019 movie) and one in *Batman: The Dark Knight Returns Part 2* (2013 animated movie); and in both Joker killed the interviewer.

Is there the same incident in comics too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The Dark Knight Returns* was a comic before it was a movie. The scene with Joker being interviewed on a chat show was part of the original comic.

[image]

Comment: It's so interesting to see that animation has drawn Robin exactly like its comic nature. BTW, why is one of them speaking German?

Comment: Because it's a parody based on  Dr Ruth, who does speak with a German accent.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruth_Westheimer   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDxIbEwm_I4

Comment: Just came back to this and found something in the picture that I am curious to ask about. In one of the mini-pictures the woman besides the Joker is holding her chest as she is being choked. But the doctor and the host are calm and intact. Does it show the doctor and the host are part of the Joker's plan?!